# Sharing a photo with text

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

The "Add a cat to that" example explains how to share a photo with my service.

But is there a way to share a photo with a text (using voice recorder) in a single item ?

Answer (score 3):

Yup! You can do this using the REPLY [built-in menu item](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#built-in-menu-items).

However, the flow is a bit different than the [Add a Cat to That](https://developers.google.com/glass/stories#add_a_cat_to_that) flow. It works like this:

1. Subscribe to updates to the `timeline` collection.
2. Insert a timeline item with the REPLY built in action specified as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#built-in-menu-items). Optionally, you can rename the menu item and customize the icon.

   ```
   {
     "text": "Hello world",
     "menuItems": [
       {
         "action": "REPLY"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. The timeline card will have a reply option in its menu. When the user selects it, they will be prompted to speak.
4. A new timeline card is then created which contains the text transcription and has an attached audio recording. Your Glassware has access to this card.
5. Your Glassware is then [notified](https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#reply) about this item insertion. The notification looks something like this:

   ```
   {
     "collection": "timeline",
     "itemId": "3hidvm0xez6r8_dacdb3103b8b604_h8rpllg",
     "operation": "INSERT",
     "userToken": "harold_penguin",
     "verifyToken": "random_hash_to_verify_referer",
     "userActions": [
       {
         "type": "REPLY"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Fetch the indicated timeline item to access the transcribed text (in the `text` property) and the [attached](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/get) audio recording

Comment: Just to see if I understand this, Jenny, the full flow would be like:  1.1 the user shares a photo a la "add a cat to that", 2 the service inserts the timeline card (perhaps with the photo in it) for the user to annotate

Comment: I understand your question better. Yup! That's pretty much it. You can also update the timeline card for the shared photo if you like. You can add the `reply` menu item. This allows users to reply to that card.

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick answer !